# Using Public Nodes in IOTA Tangle for testing purpose

Tags: iota-network, tangle, masked-authenticated-messaging

I want to send some string data using MAM over IOTA Tangle. Right now, I am using devnet. I want to know how can we test our transactions using public nodes on Mainnet? What is the process for it? I could not seem to find any instructions on how to set up public node to pass transaction using MAM. Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, are you able to send your MAM transactions to the Devnet at the moment? If so, can you share the code that you're using to connect to the Devnet?

Comment: Hey, I have used [this](https://docs.iota.org/docs/client-libraries/0.1/mam/js/create-public-channel) code to send MAM transactions to the Devnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the URL in the `provider` field to a node that's on the [Mainnet](https://docs.iota.org/docs/getting-started/0.1/network/iota-networks#mainnet).

You can use this URL as an example: https://nodes.thetangle.org/

Or, you can [run your own node](https://docs.iota.org/docs/node-software/0.1/iri/how-to-guides/install-iri).

Be sure to use a [minimum weight magnitude](https://docs.iota.org/docs/getting-started/0.1/network/minimum-weight-magnitude) of at least 14 for the Mainnet.

For example, for the code you linked to, you need to use something like the following:

```
const provider = 'https://nodes.thetangle.org/';
await Mam.attach(message.payload, message.address, 3, 14 /*this is the minimum weight magntiude*/)
```